# How hot water burn works?

Tags: human-biology, skin, epidemiology

At age of 6 I accidentally dipped my hand into a boiling indian curry(Sambar) which was in a large pot.
I got a Boiling Water Burn(Just like in the picture but with a little more radius) in my hand right away and my grandma applied some toothpaste on the area. It has been 11 years now and I still have that mark in my hand.

[image: Burn Mark]

The question is why is the mark in the center(In circle form)  of my hand and not spread down the whole hand which was  completely submerged a little above the mark. The curry's temperature was pretty uniform around the whole mixture.

Comment: The heat takes some seconds to travel through the skin into the deeper layers of the skin, and the deeper it gets, the bigger the scar zone is, it also depends on the skin thickness. Perhaps when you shook and treated your hand, you managed to cool down all the zones further away than the scarred zone fast enough so that it was superficial, or the scar zone had thinner skin, or it was both. AFAIK you should dip a burn into cool water to prevent it getting deep ASAP?